# Destructure an argument, giving defaults for some but not all fields

Tags: typescript

I have a function which accepts an object as a parameter, with defaults for values, which are merged with input

```
interface IGeneratorOptions {
  stdout?: any;
  stderr?: any;
  cwd?: string;
};

export default async (
  { name, steps }: GeneratorDefinition,
  {
    stdout,
    stderr,
    cwd
  }: IGeneratorOptions
): Promise<object> => {
  stdout = stdout || process.stdout;
  stderr = stderr || process.stderr;
  cwd = cwd || path.normalize(`${__dirname}/../../../`);

}
```

I want to be able to have someone specify a `cwd` without nulling out `stderr` and `stdout` defaults. So

`func()` should yield defaults for all 3 opts
`func({ cwd: 'hi' })` should yield defaults for `stderr` and `stdout` but keep `hi` as the passed value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```js
export default async (
  { name, steps }: GeneratorDefinition,
  {
    stdout = process.stdout,
    stderr = process.stderr,
    cwd = path.normalize(`${__dirname}/../../../`)
  }: IGeneratorOptions = {}
): Promise<object> => {
  // Whatever code you wanted here.
}
```

The first three defaults are used when an object is passed to the function that is missing the property. The final `= {}` is if no argument is passed — then the previous defaults are filled in.